# while doing chef deployment cookbooks are not uploaded on hosted chef

Tags: chef-infra

Hello guys I am new to chef and started learning from [here](http://opscode.com) please help me I m stuck into the error while uploading the cookbook into hosted-chef

While running this command in Git bash

> $ knife cookbook upload -a

I am getting this error, I have paste the one line inside the cookbook aliases that depends `magic_shell` and its saying that its not available at hosted chef please help me to get out of this error.

```
Uploading aliases      [0.1.0]
ERROR: Cookbook aliases depends on cookbook 'magic_shell' version '>= 0.0.0',
ERROR: which is not currently being uploaded and cannot be found on the server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will find the answer of my question by browsing on net it is like that I have downloaded all the cookbooks from opscode.com but I did is that upload the cookbook aliases created by me and I entered the line into its metadat.rb file is that it depends on magic_shell cookbook so,I have to upload first magic_shell cookbook then try to upload aliases

Answer (score 1):

It seems your dependency check failed. Before uploading the chef cookbook, cookbooks are compiled. While compiling chef will check for all dependencies. You can check these dependencies in `metadata.rb` file.

Can you able to find `depends "aliases"` in `metadata.rb` file of `magic_shell` cookbook.

It means `magic_shell` depends on `aliases` cookbook. To resolve this try this command

```
knife cookbook site download aliases
```

Execute above command for each dependencies. Now try

```
knife cookbook upload -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh's answer correct identifies root cause.

What I would additionally suggest is investigate the use of one of the following tools:

- [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/)
- [librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef)

What they do is manage cookbook dependencies for you, automatically downloading missing cookbooks and saving lots of time.